# Which UI components are commonly used by default by color_primary and color_secondary?

Tags: android, material-design

I'm trying to program my theme following Material Theming practice, and understand that primary color is the 'main' color throughout the app; secondary color, is something for floating button(FAB).

But I'm struggling to find out: What other UI components that primary_color|secondary_color should be applied upon for, in general?

*I've looked on this link, but seems like those color concept is very dependable*
https://material.io/design/color/applying-color-to-ui.html#

Comment: Check this [link](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Color.md#using-the-color-theming-system)

Comment: thanks mate. I've also looked on it before posted the question. But in practice seems to be more than that. Specifically this sentence, "The color displayed most frequently across your app’s screens and components.", which I found not only used for AppBar background, isn't it? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Correct. Not only AppBar. All the material components uses the primary color.

Answer (score 0):

**colorPrimary -** The color of the app bar.

**color secondary -** light version of colorprimary

**colorAccent -** The color of UI controls such as check boxes, radio buttons, and edit text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

So maybe this question should be tagged as design or material-design rather than android, that’s why people were kinda down voting me, which is pretty sad.. Not sure how inappropriate my question is to the down-voter... Anyway, I found out the closest answer to my question is:

Primary-color is used in almost all the material components, because it is used to illustrate color of your **brand**. So that can be used in multiple UI components such as:

- background color: appbar, bottom bar or some screens
- Headlines color
- Title color
- Selected state
- etc.

For example, consider the Crane app show case can be found @ [Material Study: Crane](https://material.io/design/material-studies/crane.html), the icon background color, we can see it’s purple(suggestive brand home color). It could have primary_variant, i.e: ‘darker’ purple in the example.. BUT overall it’s used to demonstrate the unique color of the brand. Another example is Facebook should have primary color blue.

Secondary-color is used to illustrate important/informative actions and should be **highlighted** and **constrast** especially when it’s near primary-color, which maybe designed under:

- FAB
- Focused state for selective UI component
- Headlines
- Button text color
- Highlight for the calendar
- etc.

Some of the app may not have secondary color, for example, newspaper like NewYork Times app.

Finally, thinking in term of primary_color and secondary_color, is not about specifically which component should use the color, it’s about how we semantically lay out our app, in term of brand, communication, information.